# Which book or blog for Facebook + PHP newbie?

Tags: php, facebook

I am going to develop a PHP app with Facebook integration. Any book/blog/sample you recommend? The features of the app are:

- only logged-in Facebook users can access the app
- the app will post an status message on the user's wall on request (e.g. I'm answering this interesting survey)
- the app is a survey, records answers which links to a user's Facebook ID
- each facebook user can answer once only
- the app wil send a summary of the survey to the user's facebook email

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one and only source i can recommend it's [their reference guide](http://developers.facebook.com/).

Of course there's a possibility you can't find some information there but there's no better starting point than this.

Comment: Most results returned by Google are so out-dated... sigh